# No such module 'GoogleMobileAds' in googleads_mobile_ios_swift_native_advanced_example

Tags: swift, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to use the 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' package for Swift. I keep the error "No such module 'GoogleMobileAds'". I have tried every solution on Stack overflow to no avail. I am using the project googleads_mobile_ios_swift_native_advanced_example found here: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/releases. I changed nothing in the project, I just ran pod install in the project then tried to run.

Comment: did you manage to run it?

Answer (score 0):

1. clone the project using git clone from:

   https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples.git
2. navigate to the project folder > Swift > admob > NativeAdvancedExample

   ```
   cd googleads-mobile-ios-examples-master/Swift/admob/NativeAdvancedExample
   ```
3. `pod install`
4. open `NativeAdvancedExample.xcworkspace` and change your `Team` and `Bundle Identifier` from TARGETS > Singing & Capabilities
5. done! now run the project.

[image]